# Default Storage account for Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I created a Windows virtual machine with OS + 1 data disk, which storage account the disk are stored. Is there any default storage account? I am using my free azure account and currently I don't have any storage account created? I am confused with where the disk are stored.

Comment: With Managed Disks, Azure manages the storage account for you. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview

Answer (score 0):

In Azure, all the data disks are the managed disk and managed by Azure. It shows you the disk resource to you in your resource group. But actually, the disks are also stored in the Azure storage account which managed by Azure and you cannot see it. Only when you export the data disk you can see it like this:

[image]